# Access: dynamically query tables

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I built an Access database to contain information regarding parts that we use to create schematics. There is one table that contain "basic" information, like "unique part ID" ("TUPID"), links to datasheets and so on - and the "Partition" further information is stored.
Furthermore there are several tables (this is "Partition") that contain information on the part itself: one table for resistors, one for connectors, one for power-ICs and so on. Each table has many fields different from other tables, but there are fields that exist on each table, eg. "Manufacturer", "Symbol", "Package" and "Height".

Now I have a split form ("10_Change_BaseInformation") that shows the "basic information", so when I select one row in the database-part of the form, the data is loaded into textboxes and can be edited. Additionally I want to see the information from the "Partition"-table in this form, so I wrote this:

```
Private Sub Form_Click()
    Dim SelectedPartition   As String:    SelectedPartition = Forms![10_Change_BaseInformation]![Text25]
        'Field "Text25" contains the TUPID
    Dim SQLStatement        As String
    
    SQLStatement = "SELECT " & SelectedPartition & ".TUPID, " & SelectedPartition & ".[Mfg]" & vbCr & _
                    "FROM " & SelectedPartition & vbCr & _
                    "WHERE (((" & SelectedPartition & ".TUPID)=[Forms]![10_Change_BaseInformation]![TUPID]));"
    

    DoCmd.RunSQL SQLStatement
    ' SQLStatement = "SELECT Resistor.TUPID, Resistor.[Hersteller] FROM ResistorWHERE (((Resistor.TUPID)=[Forms]![10_Change_BaseInformation]![TUPID]));"
End Sub
```

First of all, I get runtime-error "2342", but I can't make any sense of that; so: how do I have to modify my code, to get a valid result?
Second, how can I get the values from the query to the form?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Might it be whitespace before your WHERE clause? " WHERE"
If your commented out SQL is from output Print statement it looks like it would cause syntax issues.

Comment: *one table for resistors, one for connectors, one for power-ICs and so on.* ... reconsider this database design of similarly structured tables that differ by category. Instead, normalize to a *single* table with a category field. Doing so, you avoid complex queries like dynamic SQL you are attempting and enjoy a more efficient, scalable, and maintainable schema.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the reason of your error, as we would need more information such as the types of your fields in your table.

I'm guessing that your Resistor.TUPID field is a string.

If so, you need to modify your code as below:

```
WHERE (((" & SelectedPartition & ".TUPID)='" & [Forms]![10_Change_BaseInformation]![TUPID] & "'));
```

If it is of Type number then

```
WHERE (((" & SelectedPartition & ".TUPID)=" & [Forms]![10_Change_BaseInformation]![TUPID] & "));
```

As to the form...

Generally speaking, you can design a form without a record source, but with *controls that are named the same as your select query fields*.

When designing each Control on the form, you have to explicitly specify the Control Source (i.e. The field names that are returned from your select query), otherwise they will be Unbound and never update automatically based on Record Source.

Then assign your SQL query string to the Recordsource of the form.

```
MyForm.Recordsource = MySQLString
```

Then run the Requery method of the form.

```
MyForm.Requery
```